# How to/difficulty of transferring immobiliser related wires in an ignition switch harness?

Tags: electrical, ignition, immobilizer

Was replacing ignition switch and realised it had an immobiliser related wire on it which needed to be transferred over.  I have no real knowledge of electronics.

1. How does one go about moving these wires from the harness over properly? What tool is needed, what terms should I google to see this in action etc
2. Rather than get car towed I was thinking of giving switches to local(usually incompetent) garages and asking them to move wire over, is this something that is very easy to do or is it something that is easy to mess up in which case I might have to take it further afield?
3. How long would this task typically take a mechanic?

[image]

Comment: Can you highlight which wire you are talking about and where it needs to go to?

Comment: I need to go look at both harnesses again, however isn’t the mechanism to move and replace these wires all the same?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to pull a single wire out of that connector casing?

Comment: No, I think it’s 2 that are related to the immobiliser.  I will need to pull them out correctly then put them in same slots of replacement switch harness/casing I assume. I did get a mobile mechanic And he was using a tool which looked like a screw driver but with a hook on the end, he was really struggling and couldn’t do it.  Told me to take it to his garage later but I’m worried he might not know what he’s doing hence this question.

Comment: Usually you can just use a ‘jewellers screwdriver’ to push back a lug that holds the connector in.  It is difficult to describe, but generally easy to do if you examine the connector casing.